# show realtime total visitors

Tags: php, jquery

I tried to show real time visitors visit(ed) the site. Below is my PHP file named `getTotalVisitors`. In the php file the `uniquevisitors` are showing well.

```
include 'common.php'; //get database connection

$query = "SELECT SUM(uniquevisitors) as uniquevisitors  FROM " . $DBPrefix . "currentaccesses"; 

$params = array();
$db->query($query, $params);

while ($new = $db->fetch())
 {  
    $uniquevisitors = $new['uniquevisitors'];

 }
 echo "visitors until now: " .   $uniquevisitors . "<br>";
```

When i try to get it real time with the update and setInterval function with the below script, I cannot get it working. Anybody gives me the right direction/solution ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    function updategetTotalVisitors()
       {
         $('#datashow').load('getTotalVisitors.php');
       }
    updategetTotalVisitors(); //set the datacount as soon as the page is loaded
    setInterval( "updategetTotalVisitors()", 10000 ); //update the datashow every 10 seconds
    });
 </script>
 <p>Visitors until now:</p>
 <div id = "datashow"></div>
```

Comment: What works, what doesn't work? What happens when you run it (or doesn't happen)? What kind of debugging have you already done?

Comment: the php file works, the script don't work.

Comment: Check the console for possible errors.

Comment: But aren't you treating that first argument of `setInterval` as a string? I'm not too good with JavaScript, I found this question from the php-tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the function parameter of `setInterval` must be unquoted and without parenthesis:

```
setInterval( updategetTotalVisitors, 10000 );
```

Then, you have to declare `updategetTotalVisitors` outside `$(document).ready` scope and to assign the returned value of `setInterval` to a variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var repeatFunction;

    function updategetTotalVisitors()
    {
        $('#datashow').load( 'getTotalVisitors.php' );
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        updategetTotalVisitors();
        repeatFunction = setInterval( updategetTotalVisitors, 10000 );
    });
</script>
```

The script above works, for me. Obviously I have tested it with fake *getTotalVisitors.php*, but you say that your php works, so...

Comment: I copied your script and deleted my script. Only the text 'visitors until now' is showing up twice.

Comment: you have to maintain the jquery init script, obviously. also have you checked js console for error info?

Comment: This is my html file

Comment: This... which?? You have to replace in your html **ONLY** the corresponding part.

Comment: If I run the html file (see below) the php file renews every 10 seconds. How can I get the result from php fle in my div in my html ?

Comment: `$('#datashow').load( 'getTotalVisitors.php' );` **Have you checked browser js console?**

Comment: @user1392475 [Here](http://goo.gl/B8Zmff) you can find working example. You can also download source. Obviously my “getTotalVisitors.php” is fake, because I don't have access to your database.